# Execute SQL queries before open cursor and after closing it in JdbcCursorItemReader

Tags: java, sql, spring-batch

I want to use A JdbcCursorItemReader to read data from the database,
The main sql query of this ItemReader is something like :

```
Select
    TABLE1.col1,
    TMP_TABLE.num1,
    TABLE1.col2
From 
    TABLE1, TMP_TABLE
WHERE -- some conditions
```

The problem here is that the data in the TMP_TABLE should be inserted before executing this main query, and also should be deleted after.

insert data using queries like (I want this one to be run before opening the cursor ):

```
insert into TMP_TABLE (NUM1) value (:x);
insert into TMP_TABLE (NUM2) value (:y);
```

deleting data using query like (I want this one to be run after closing the cursor):

```
delete from TMP_TABLE
```

Is there any way to do this using the JdbcCursorItemReader ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `StepExecutionListener` to handle this.  You can populate the data in the `StepExecutionListener#beforeStep()` method and delete it in the `StepExecutionListener#afterStep()` method.  You can read more about this listener in the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/step.html#stepExecutionListener